# Giving PHP include()'d files parent variable scope

Tags: php, function, include, scope

Is there anyway to for an included file to be used in a parent scope to the one it was called in? The following example is simplified, but does the same job.

In essence, a file will be included by a function, but would like the scope of the included file to be the scope of where the function that included it was called from.

main.php:

```
<?php
  if(!function_exists('myPlugin'))
  {
    function myPlugin($file)
      {
        if(file_exists($file)
        {
          require $file;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
  }

  $myVar = 'something bar foo';

  $success = myPlugin('included.php');

  if($success)
  {
    echo $myResult;
  }
```

included.php:

```
<?php
  $myResult = strlen($myVar);
```

Thanks in advance,
Alexander.

### EDIT: Solution

Well, sort of, thanks to the contributions by Chacha102.
Can be called from within a class now too!

main.php

```
<?php
  class front_controller extends controller
  {
    public function index_page()
    {
      $myVar = 'hello!';

      // This is the bit that makes it work.
      // I know, wrapping it in an extract() is ugly,
      // and the amount of parameters that you can't change...
      extract(load_file('included.php', get_defined_vars(), $this));

      var_dump($myResult);
    }
    public function get_something()
    {
      return 'foo bar';
    }
  }

  function load_file($_file, $vars = array(), &$c = null)
  {
    if(!file_exists($_file))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if(is_array($vars))
    {
      unset($vars['c'], $vars['_file']);
      extract($vars);
    }
    require $_file;
    return get_defined_vars();
  }
```

included.php:

```
<?php
  $myResult = array(
    $myVar,
    $c->get_something()
  );
```

If you want to reference a method it has to be public, but the result is as expected:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "hello!"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "foo bar"
}
```

Now, this doesn't really have any practical use, and the only reason I wanted to know how to do this is because I am stubborn. The thought came into my head, and would not let it defeat me :D

`<rant>`
Thanks to all who contributed. Except the person who boo'd me. It was a simple enough question, and have now figured out that (complicated) solution exists.
Screw whether it "conforms to the PHP way of doing things". Ever told a client "Oh no, we shouldn't do that, it's not the correct way to do things!"? Thought not.
`</rant>`

Thanks again to Chacha102 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function include_use_scope($file, $defined_variables)
{
    extract($defined_variables);
    include($file);
}

include_use_scope("file.php", get_defined_vars());
```

`get_defined_vars()` gets ALL variables defined in the scope it is called in. `extract()` takes an array and defines them as local variables.

```
extract(array("test"=>"hello"));
echo $test; // hello

$vars = get_defined_vars();
echo $vars['test']; //hello
```

Thus, the desired result is achieved. You might want to strip out the superglobals and stuff from the variables however, as overwriting them might be bad.

Check out this [comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php#73608) for stripping the bad ones out.

In order to get the reverse, you could do something like this:

```
function include_use_scope($file, $defined_variables)
{
    extract($defined_variables);
    return include($file);
}

extract(include_use_scope("file.php", get_defined_vars()));
```

include.php

```
// do stuff
return get_defined_vars();
```

But all in all, I don't think you are going to get the desired effect, as this was not how PHP was built.

Comment: How would main.php then get access to included.php's local vars, as in OP's code?

Comment: Gah ... Overlooked that part of it. I'll put in my answer that it is only one way, as I believe a two-way operation just isn't going to work.

Comment: I came up with a solution that the file can return the defined variables, and then the main file can extract them .. but it seems really hacky and annoying.

Comment: This did give me a great idea on how to do it. It's long winded, complicated, and not really necessary. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know how to is to use the superglobal array.

main.php:

```
  $GLOBALS['myVar'] = 'something bar foo';

  $success = myPlugin('included.php');

  if($success)
  {
    echo $GLOBALS['myResult'];
  }
```

included.php:

```
<?php
  $GLOBALS['myResult'] = strlen($GLOBALS['myVar']);
```